# Permissions difficulty accessing remote '/' with CIFS

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-mint, samba, cifs

I'm having trouble accessing the root directory of another Linux machine. 
In my fstab I have two entries for the machine in question

```
//ltotto/root   /mnt/ltroot     cifs    auto,users,credentials=/home/otto/.smbcredentials,uid=otto,gid=otto,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,iocharset=utf8 0 0
//ltotto/otto   /mnt/ltotto     cifs    auto,users,credentials=/home/otto/.smbcredentials,uid=otto,gid=otto,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

i.e. both to the same machine with the same credentials. On the other machine there are two Samba shares 'root' and 'otto' for '/' and '/home/otto' respectively, both with write permission for the user otto.

Both are mounted with no errors and the 'otto' mount works perfectly. 
The 'root' mount however is the problem

```
ls -la /mnt/ltroot/
ls: /mnt/ltroot/var: Permission denied
ls: /mnt/ltroot/lib64: Permission denied
ls: /mnt/ltroot/cdrom: Permission denied
[etc]
```

I can't understand why the home mount is fine and the root mount not. Can anyone explain and suggest a solution?

Note: I'm sure this configuration worked perfectly until recently.

EDIT: The Samba configuration of the remote machine:

```
[root]
    comment = file system root
    path = /
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = otto

[otto]
    path = /home/otto
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = otto
    comment = otto's Home
```

Comment: You should be looking at the configuration of the Samba server in question.

Comment: You need execute, not write permission to navigate a directory.

Comment: @all The remote Samba server is properly configured with write access for the named user. Samba does not have an execute option only read or write.